# QGraphicsScene draw a non transformable circle

Tags: qt, qt5

I am trying to draw a 10 pixel radius circle on a QGraphicsScene that is anchored on the center and doesn't transform (change size) when the scene is zoomed.

I have tried using the QGraphicsEllipseItem with the QGraphicsItem::ItemIgnoresTransformations flag, but it still transforms when the scene is zoomed.

Is this possible with standard graphics items, or do I need to create my own and do the paint event manually?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Do you just surf around looking for questions without code to make that comment? I am literally asking how to do it, because I don't know how, therefore I have no code.

Comment: You stated `"I have tried using the QGraphicsEllipseItem with the QGraphicsItem::ItemIgnoresTransformations flag, but it still transforms when the scene is zoomed"`.  I would have thought `QGraphicsItem::ItemIgnoresTransformations` would do exactly what you want.  Hence my request for the code.

Comment: QGraphicsEllipseItem seemed like a logical starting point, especially with the ItemIgnoresTransformations, however, it requires a rectangle, and abides by the dimensions specified in that rectangle when zooming, so it cannot work (at least that I am aware of). I can't believe this isn't possible in Qt, but given the size of Qt scene capabilities, I am not finding a solution. Hence I have no code

Comment: I'm still confused.  If you add a language tag (c++, python?) to your question I'll post some code that I *think* should work (or at least provide a starting point).

Comment: Any language will do. I code in many daily. This particular task is in C++, but I use PyQt5 daily also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code does what I *think* you're looking for.  It creates a single 10 pixel immutable circle that anchors itself to the centre of the scene as well as 10 larger, movable, circles that obey the scaling transform applied...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsEllipseItem>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QPainter>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QGraphicsView view;
  QGraphicsScene scene;
  view.setScene(&scene);
  QGraphicsEllipseItem immutable(0, 0, 20, 20);
  immutable.setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIgnoresTransformations);
  immutable.setPen(Qt::NoPen);
  immutable.setBrush(Qt::blue);
  scene.addItem(&immutable);
  QObject::connect(&scene, &QGraphicsScene::sceneRectChanged,
                   [&](const QRectF &rect)
                     {
                       immutable.setPos(rect.center() - 0.5 * immutable.boundingRect().center());
                     });
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    auto *e = new QGraphicsEllipseItem(20, 20, 50, 50);
    e->setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable | QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);
    scene.addItem(e);
  }
  view.show();
  view.setTransform(QTransform::fromScale(5, 2));
  return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thank you that works (or is at least close enough that I can make the edits). What is frustrating, is I tried that same basic thing and hundreds of variants and none work. There must be an ordering to the operations I didn't try that matters. Sorry for being snarky earlier